# How to Run Datalore locally?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, jetbrains-ide, datalore

How do I run datalore (Which is a data science tool for python made by jetbrains) locally like jupyter?

Link : [datalore.io](http://datalore.io)

Answer (score 4):

Datalore is now available as an on-premises installation for companies. Check this out: https://www.jetbrains.com/datalore/enterprise/

Comment: Great for companies. Individuals on the other hand are SOL. You can install it locally on a Kubernetes cluster (and soon with mere Docker) but the documentation calls for a license key so we likely won't be able to actually run Datalore locally. Shame too because it's really neat. On-prem solutions continue to be completely gimped for the homelab community.